# using ".slideToggle()" with multiple buttons individually

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried adding multiple buttons, when i click on one button, the rest get clicked too.

How can i have each button toggles individually?

Also, how can i have them all hidden by default on page load?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>slideToggle demo</title>
  <style>
  p {
    width: 400px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<button>Toggle 1</button>
<p>
 Text 1
</p>

<button>Toggle 2</button>
<p>
 Text 2
</p>
 
<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks everyone, every code worked!

There's only one last thing, how can i have multiple buttons with its unique paragraph within a main button?

example:

```
[MainButton.A] <--(Shows additional buttons when clicked)
[ButtonA.1] <--(Shows it's own paragraph when clicked, same as the rest)
[ButtonA.2]

[MainButton.B]
[ButtonB.1]
[ButtonB.2]
```

Comment: `$(this).next( "p" ).slideToggle( "slow" );`

Comment: You are targeting all the elements. instead of that, use a **CLASS** or an **ID** to target each.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("p").hide();//hides all <p> initially shows only button clicked..
   $( "button" ).click(function() {
     $(this).next( "p" ).slideToggle( "slow" );  
   });
});
</script>
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ohes689y/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that all of the *buttons* are being clicked; it's that all of the *paragraph* elements are being manipulated every time a button is clicked.

@ArunPJohny's comment has the solution:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).next("p").slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

What this does is select the *next* `<p>` element rather than all of them. Note the `.next()` selector here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Answer

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>slideToggle demo</title>
  <style>
  p {
    width: 400px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<button class="btncls">Toggle 1</button>
<p>
 Text 1
</p>

<button class="btncls">Toggle 2</button>
<p>
 Text 2
</p>
 
<script>
$(".btncls").click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle( "slow" );
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```